# How to put 2 rows of images inside a 'column' using flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a site using flex boxes. I have a div with 2 'columns' inside, and 2 'rows' inside of the second 'column' which I have to fill with two images each, the problem is the images doesn't fit into the 'rows' and exceeds its width.

I need my images stretch or shrink with the navigator size, so I can't use px for their size.

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

And this is what I get:

[image: What I get]

Here is my code:

```css
#offices {
  background: peachpuff;      
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;      
}
.row {
  background: red;
  line-height: 0;
  display: flex;
}
#officesImg img {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="offices">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="officesImg">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/xVWwKa)

PD: Please avoid float solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `#officesImg` to `display:flex`. And removed `height:100%` from the `img` that causes aspect ration issue on Firefox.

```css
#offices {
  background: peachpuff;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em;
  flex: 1;
}
#officesImg {
  line-height: 0;
  display: flex;
}
#officesImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="offices">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="officesImg">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a slightly polished version that matches your wireframe.

```css
#offices {
  background: peachpuff;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em;
  flex: 1;
}
#officesImg {
  line-height: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: .5em;
}
#officesImg img {
  width: calc(100% - 1em);
  height: auto;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="offices">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="officesImg">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_01_zpsewjzabzm.jpg" />
      <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/office_02_zpsdz0zixcd.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution is to wrap each image element in a div.

In other words:

```
<div><img ... ></div>
```

Images remain responsive and aspect ratio is maintained.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNYdaj?editors=1100)